# Deliver cache content from varnish if request comes from new IP

Tags: cache, varnish

I have setup varnish in magento2. Suppose my website is https://example.com. When I request with curl -I https://example.com I got header value Age: 0 . In next request Age value increases.                                                       When I login to another server and request with curl -I https://example.com again I got the header Age: 0 . It is not fetching from varnish cache.                                                      Can I configure varnish to cache common contents for different requesting clients ? So if a request comes from a new IP it should deliver the cache content.

Comment: Can you post complete VCL that you're using? What you describe is not how it's supposed to work. (it should deliver from cache irrespective of where you request from).

Comment: I used the default Magento varnish vcl file